# Provider only if authenticated

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm developing a booking app using riverpod and I have an issue when the user disconnect.
I don't know if it is an issue or i am using riverpod in the wrong way, but in this app the first screen you see is the login page.
After you login many providers get instantiated using the user id logged in.

I made a simplification of the flow that I am using that I paste below.

The problem occur when the user disconnect, because the provider that should be used only in the authenticated screen (because it is referentiated only there) gets rigthly disposed but then it gets instantiated again, causing the error.

I can of course handle this in the *OnlyIfAuthenticatedStateNotifier* checking in the constructor if the user is logged in and then do things accordingly. But I would like to understand why if I'm using that notifier only in the authenticated part, when I disconnect it get reinstantiated.

Thank you all

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';

/// hold the authenticated state of the user
final isAuthenticated = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);

/// provider that should be used only in authenticated part of the app
final onlyIfAuthenticatedProvider = StateNotifierProvider<OnlyIfAuthenticatedStateNotifier, List<int>>((ref) {

  print('Creating new OnlyIfAuthenticatedStateNotifier');
  ref.onDispose(() { print('Disposed OnlyIfAuthenticatedStateNotifier'); });

  final _isAuthenticated = ref.watch(isAuthenticated);
  if (!_isAuthenticated.state) { throw UnsupportedError('Not authenticated'); }

  return OnlyIfAuthenticatedStateNotifier();

});

/// Dumb notifier
class OnlyIfAuthenticatedStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<int>> {
  OnlyIfAuthenticatedStateNotifier(): super([1,2,3]);
}

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ref.watch(isAuthenticated).state ? AuthenticatedPage() : UnathenticatedPage()
      
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticatedPage extends ConsumerWidget {

  const AuthenticatedPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('Authenticated'),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){ ref.read(isAuthenticated).update((state) => false); }, child: const Text('Logout')),
            SizedBox(
              height:200,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: ref.watch(onlyIfAuthenticatedProvider).length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('$index')
                  );
                }
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UnathenticatedPage extends ConsumerWidget {

  const UnathenticatedPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('Unathenticated'),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){ ref.read(isAuthenticated).update((state) => true); }, child: const Text('Login'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that way is working but the doc's says "DON'T CALL READ INSIDE THE BODY OF A PROVIDER" https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers/#can-i-read-a-provider-without-listening-to-it. Maybe I should pass down the reader object to the providers and manage the logic there if the user is authenticated or not

Answer (score 0):

I had just posted an answer suggesting to use `read` in your provider and double checked the docs and... *don't do that*. It looks like you're watching that state just to do an assertion which is probably unnecessary.

The Provider is definitely being recreated because your watching that state so whether it's changing to `true` or to `false` it's going to be called.

Here's what the docs say on this subject.

[My provider updates too often, what can I do?](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers#my-provider-updates-too-often-what-can-i-do)

Comment: Yes indeed I'm not listening to the Authstate but only to the portion I need